# jQuery Datatable Modal - Add information

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to do the following. 
When you click on any one line, open a modal with the information of line and a ComboBox with information from another table and insert it into a new table in database.
My question is, can do this via a modal? How?

Thank you.
Follow my source.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "Copy"
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "sButtonText": "Print"
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "pdf"]
                }]
            },
            "autoWidth": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Load_Arm_tec.php",
            "aoColumns": [{
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "ID",
                "aTargets": [0]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "arm",
                "aTargets": [1]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "City",
                "aTargets": [2]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "reg",
                "aTargets": [3]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "QNTD",
                "aTargets": [4]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "Size",
                "aTargets": [5]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "DT_start",
                "aTargets": [6]
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "DT_end",
                "aTargets": [7],
                "type": "date"
            }, {
                "sClass": "readonly",
                "sTitle": "Days",
                "aTargets": [8]
            }],
            "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                $('td.readonly').on('click', function(e) {

                    var id = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[0];

                    //MODAL HERE....  HOW?


                });
            }
        });


    });
    </script>
```

And my HTML source..

```
<div id="dynamic">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
        id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ARM</th>
                <th>CITY</th>
                <th>REG</th>
                <th>QNTD</th>
                <th>SIZE</th>
                <th>DT_START</th>
                <th>DT_END</th>
                <th>DAYS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading..</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ARM</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th>REG</th>
            <th>QNTD</th>
            <th>SIZE</th>
            <th>DT_START</th>
            <th>DT_END</th>
            <th>DAYS</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: fnDrawCallback Whith Modal....**

**Okay, The question now is: How do I add a ComboBox with informations from my database??**

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function() {
    $('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {

        var id_armario = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[0];
        var armario = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[1];
        var cidade = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[2];

      dialog = $( "#users-contain" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          open: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + id + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + arm + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + city + "</td>" +
                     "</tr>" );
          },
          close: function( event, ui ) {
              $("#users tbody").empty();
           },
          buttons: {
            "OK": function(){
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              dialog.dialog( "close" );
            }
         }
    });
```

And the HTML for Modal...

```
<div id="users-contain">
    <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Arm</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use for example jquery dialog method with parameter modal: true.

`var dialog = $( "#example" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {
"Submit": submit,
Cancel: function() {
dialog.dialog( "close" );
}
},
close: function() {
}
});`

Comment: @Greenonion Okay. I need to bind a Form in the submit right? To fill the information of the line and add the combobox.

Comment: Please look here - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form
Tell me if you will have any problems.

Comment: @Greenonion I got you. How do I get when clicking the line open the modal with the information already filled?

Comment: Done.... The question now is: How do I add a ComboBox with informations from my database?? In this modal...

Comment: You have open event handler. My suggestion is to create separate method like bindModal() and call it when open event occur where you will populate your view with data. To get your values you can use jquery ajax method to request data from your server side. (don't know wich language you are using for backend)

Comment: @Greenonion I am using PHP ... I think I understand... Type this right? $.get( "test.php", { id: "123", arm: "abcd" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
   $( "body" )
    .append( "Data_Back: " + data.value );
  });

Comment: Yes, keep going. Let me know if any troubles.

Comment: @Greenonion Done. Now update the database again, but this is easy now. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for others who have questions. 
Problem solved.

JavaScrit...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable(
    {
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends": "copy",
                        "sButtonText": "Copy"
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "print",
                        "sButtonText": "Print"
                    },
               {
                   "sExtends":    "collection",
                   "sButtonText": "Save",
                   "aButtons":    [ "csv", "pdf" ]
               }
            ]
        },
        "autoWidth": true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "Load_Arm.php",
        "aoColumns" : [
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "ID",
                    "aTargets": [0]
                },     
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "ARM",
                    "aTargets": [1]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "CITY",
                    "aTargets": [2]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "REG",
                    "aTargets": [3]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "QNTD",
                    "aTargets": [4]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "SIZE",
                    "aTargets": [5]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "DT_START",
                    "aTargets": [6]
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "DT_END",
                    "aTargets": [7],
                    "type": "date"
                },
                {
                    "sClass" : "readonly",
                    "sTitle": "DAYS",
                    "aTargets": [8]
                }
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
            $('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {

                var id = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[0];
                var arm = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[1];
                var city = oTable.fnGetData($(this).parents('tr')[0])[2];                                        

              dialog = $( "#users-contain" ).dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 500,
                  width: 900,
                  title: "Info Arm",
                  modal: true,
                  open: function( event, ui ) {
                      $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                          "<td>" + id + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + arm + "</td>" +
                          "<td>" + city + "</td>" +
                             "</tr>" );

                      $.ajax({
                            url:'Tec_combo.php',
                            type:'POST',
                            data:'clust=' + city,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function( json ) {
                            $.each(json, function(i, value) {  
                             $('<option></option>', {text:value}).attr('value', value).appendTo('#names');
                                });
                            }
                          });

                  },
                  close: function( event, ui ) {
                      $("#users tbody").empty();
                      $("#names").empty();
                   },
                  buttons: {
                    "OK": function(){
                        dialog.dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                      dialog.dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });

              dialog.dialog("open");
            } );
        }   
    });                                     
);
</script>
```

HTML code...

```
<div id="users-contain">
<table id="users">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Arm</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <select id="names"></select>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks...
Questions, I am available...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done by cloning the model inside an each statement that loop trough the data and append it to a certain section also I recommend adding class so that it can be easier to find using jQuery find() function

$.each(datAarray,function (index, value) {
    ComboBox =  $(modal).clone()

```
ComboBox.find('.rowName').append(value);
```

})